# Fade into splash screen on game load

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm using Slick2D and LWJGL for my StateBasedGame and I was wondering if there was a way to enter into my splashscreen on application load using a transition?

I tried using:

```
this.enterState(SPLASH, new FadeInTransition(Color.black), new FadeInTransition(Color.black));
```

However, it fades in nicely but then it flashes again for the second transition :(

Anyone know how I can get around that?

Would I have to create my own transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the docs I found that I can use an empty transition to the second transition parameter to prevent the additional transition from playing.

```
this.enterState(SPLASH, new FadeInTransition(Color.black), new EmptyTransition());
```